# Error handling and recovery when making 2 future based calls

Tags: scala, future

I am making 2 calls that both return the following:

```
    def processUser(..): Future[Either[Error, UserStatus]]
    def processTransactions(..): Future[Either[Error, TransactionStatus]]
```

So I could do it like this:

```
    for {
       _ <- processUser(user)
       _ <- processTransaction(...)
    }
```

The 2 calls don't depend on each other, but `processUser` has to run before `processTransaction`.

Here are my rules:

1. if processUser returns an error, don't call `processTransaction`
2. if both succeed without an error, all is good
3. if processUser returns successfully, but `processTransaction` fails with an error that I want to call `unprocessUser`.

How can I do this?   I guess using a for comprehension is not well suited for this, what pattern is more ideal?

**Note**

I am not using cats library, just plain Scala 2.13.x with Futures.

Comment: `Future[Either[Error, ...Status]]` doesn't make much sense. If that is code under your control, you could simply fail the `Future` rather than build an `Either` to hold the `Error`.

Comment: @jwvh It's possible that there should be difference between asynchronicity errors and busyness errors so `Future.successful(Left(...))` can be possible.

Comment: Using failed `Future` to hold an error means loosing the possible type (s) of the error and having some unknown exception types to represent the error. Better use `Future` only for the asynchronous.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `Cats` you can use something called a monad transformer, specifically `EitherT` for your case:

```scala
import cats.implicits._
import cats.data.EitherT

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

type User
type UserStatus
type Transaction
type TransactionStatus

def processUser(user: User): Future[Either[Error, UserStatus]] = ???
def processTransaction(tx: Transaction): Future[Either[Error, TransactionStatus]] = ???
def unprocessUser(user: User): Future[Either[Error, TransactionStatus]]  = ???

val user : User = ???
val tx : Transaction = ???
def resCatsFuture(): Future[Either[Error, Unit]] =
  (for {
    userStatus <- EitherT(processUser(user))
    txStatus <- EitherT(processTransaction(tx))
      .handleErrorWith(e => EitherT(unprocessUser(user)))
  } yield ()).value
```

And since we are on Cats you should also consider replacing `Future` with `IO` from Cats Effect:

```scala
import cats.effect._

def processUserIO(user: User): IO[Either[Error, UserStatus]] = ???
def processTransactionIO(tx: Transaction): IO[Either[Error, TransactionStatus]] = ???
def unprocessUserIO(user: User): IO[Either[Error, TransactionStatus]]  = ???

val resCatsIO: IO[Either[Error, Unit]] =
  (for {
    userStatus <- EitherT(processUserIO(user))
    txStatus <- EitherT(processTransactionIO(tx))
      .handleErrorWith(e => EitherT(unprocessUserIO(user)))
  } yield ()).value
```

Or with `ZIO`'s typed errors as an alternative to monad transformers:

```scala
import zio._

def processUserZIO(user: User): ZIO[Any, Error, UserStatus] = ???
def processTransactionZIO(tx: Transaction): ZIO[Any, Error, TransactionStatus] = ???
def unprocessUserZIO(user: User): ZIO[Any, Error, TransactionStatus]  = ???

val resZIO: ZIO[Any, Error, Unit] =
  for {
    userStatus <- processUserZIO(user)
    txStatus <- processTransactionZIO(tx)
      .catchAll(e => unprocessUserZIO(user))
  } yield ()
```

If you want to stick to vanilla Scala you can use `fold` on the inner `Either` and return a new `Future` for both `Left` and `Right` cases so you can keep your for-comprehension going.

```scala
def unprocessUser2(user: User): Future[Transaction] = ???
def unprocessUser3(user: User): Future[Unit] = ???

val res: Future[Unit] =
  for {
    mUserStatus <- processUser(user)
    userStatus <- mUserStatus.fold(Future.failed, Future.successful) //you could also do `Future.fromTry(mUserStatus.toTry)` here
    mTxStatus <- processTransaction(tx)
    txStatus <- mTxStatus.fold(e => unprocessUser2(user), Future.successful)
    //or alternatively, depending on how you want to handle the `Left` and Right values
    _ <- mTxStatus.fold(e => unprocessUser3(user), tx => Future(println(tx)))
  } yield ()

//Redundant, but for consistency, if you want to keep to the same `Either` inner type.
val resEither: Future[Either[Error, Unit]] =
  for {
    mUserStatus <- processUser(user)
    userStatus <- mUserStatus.fold(Future.failed, Future.successful)
    mTxStatus <- processTransaction(tx)
    mTxStatus2 <- mTxStatus.fold(e => unprocessUser(user), tx => Future.successful(Right(tx)))
  } yield Right()
```

I'm making a lot assumptions about how `unprocessUser` should work and where it should be handled. There are also other error handling methods in Cats and ZIO that might be better for your use case.

Comment: I'm not using cats unfort., just plain jane scala with futures.

Comment: @Blankman added a solution w/o Cats or ZIO

Comment: Thanks, but you changed the return type, it is: `Future[Either[Error, Transaction]]` for both method calls.

Comment: @Blankman added another case for consistency, basically you just have to wrap the relevant results in a `Right` again, but it wasn't necessary because the errors have been lifted to the `Future` untyped.

Comment: It really depends on what `unprocessUser` actually have to return as well.

Comment: All my functions have the same return shape, `Future[Either[Error, T]]`

Answer (score 0):

for what you want, I think you don't need a for comprehension. Try this (please note that is writed dirrectly as an answer, can have some errors at compile)

```
processUser(user) map {
   _ => processTransaction(user) flatMap {
       _ => // do nothing
   } recover {
     case e => unprocessUser()
   }
} recover {
  case e => {
    // throw err
  }
}
```